# Android Tablet device can't connect PC

Tags: android

I have an android tablet "Galaxy Tab 10.1" and need to connect to my pc to debug but it even doesnt show up on Device Manager when I plug the cable. I saw many solutions and tried it, like:
Downloaded samsung usb driver from here:
http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/GT-P7510MAYXAB
Also in settings USB debugging is enabled.

But there is still no change! Is there any suggestion?? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It doesn't show up in DeviceManager *at all*? Or does it show as an unknown device?

Comment: Have you installed the Samsung Drivers?

Comment: I did from the link which i wrote, but first of all i need to see the device in DeviceManager right? so that after i can update driver etc.

Comment: Samsung drivers are a bit iffy. I've preloaded a dozen laptops for a mass-rollout and used a 22MB file that Samsung gave us. Meanwhile, you can try this: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=961956

Comment: However, if you plug in your tablet, the device manage should show at least an unknown device. If not, try a different cable or USB port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I changed the cable, reinstalled the drivers and worked :)

Answer (score 2):

Go to Settings->Select Storage->Click on the three dots->Usb Computer Connection->Experiment with either MTP or Camera. For my phone it works only with Camera mode.

Comment: i'm on 4.2.2 and there is no menu (three dots) on the storage page.

Comment: For a Samsung TAB A6 Galaxy,  I had to change my connection from MTP to PTP (Picture Transfer Protocol)

Answer (score 1):

After you plugged in try to shutdown and then power on the tablet whilst connected. It solved my issue. Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

You could try turning USB debugging off. Also, is there maybe a setting to change the USB mode in settings? Most Android devices have one somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this quite a bit, and it seems that happens when the Samsung connector on the bottom of the device is not properly seated.  Remove and firmly re-connect has solved the issue a few times for me.

Disconnecting & rebooting the device, run "adb kill-server", reconnect device, run "adb devices" - seems to solve a good few issues also.

Answer (score 0):

Hi There i got a Simple Solution to share.

1st step: Dont connect your android tablet or phone on the computer in this time. :)

2nd step: if your android tablet or phone is on then TURN IT OFF!!

3rd step: NOW after you turn it OFF turn it ON again then connect to the computer Via USB    cable..... SEE IF IT WORKS

Answer (score 0):

download Kies and it will automatically download all required drivers - samsung file sync app

read more: http://www.samsung.com/latin_en/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/JSP

download: http://www.samsung.com/us/kies/

Comment: I have the same problem. I tried this, and no improvement. When I plug in my tablet to a USB cable, I get an "Unknown Device" in the control panel with an exclamation mark.

Answer (score 0):

Okay Android made this much harder than it needs to be (as usual).

I fought this for two days and finally found a way to turn USB sharing on on the tablet. I loaded the drivers to the computer and it recognized the device but would not read it. The solution was to go to settings, storage and then ignore everything in the storage box. In the top left corner a USB symbol will appear very small next to the sd card logo (if one is mounted) Long Press and drag that down to open a message box. There will be an option to turn on USB sharing.